# Joint Probabilities range of $x$ and $y$

Tags: probability

Hi this is the question:

Consider the following joint probability density function (PDF) of $X$ and $Y$ :

$f(x,y) = 4xy$
$0 < y < 1,~0 < x < 1,$

Find $P(X < Y)$.

What I don't understand is that during integration, for the respective range of $x$ and $y$, shouldn't it be

$0 < x < y$

$x < y < 1$

and not

$0 < x < 1$

$x < y < 1$

Can someone please explain why the second range of values is correct?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @jy.chua Both are actually correct; $0<x<y<1$ can be split into $0<x<y$ and $x<y<1$, or $0<x<1$ and $x<y<1$.

Comment: @ju.chua The first range is wrong. It should read 0 < x < y, 0 < y < 1. Otherwise the boundaries are illdefined in the integralls: $$ \int_0^y dx\int_x^1 dy $$ or $$ \int_x^1 dy\int_0^y dx $$ make no sense since you have integration parameters outside of the integrals.

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d. So the probability is $1/2$.

Comment: @denklo now  I understand I cannot have two integration parameters outside of the integrals at the same time as I will not be able to solve the problem, but is that the only reason why I can only have one parameter outside the integral? Are there more reasons to explain why the range of one of the parameters must be 0<y<1 or 0<x<1?

Comment: @jy.chua I think the boundaries are most formaly derived using the characteristic functions $[ ... ]$, as drhab did in his answer. Notice, how the outer integration variable spans the whole support, the inner one however is effectively limited by the condition $x<y$. Unfortunately i'm not able to come up with some more elegant explanation.

Comment: @denklo thanks a lot for your help!!!

Answer (score 2):

$$P(X<Y)=\mathbb E\mathsf1_{X<Y}=\int\int [x<y]f_{X,Y}(x,y)dxdy=\int\int [x<y]f_{X,Y}(x,y)dydx$$where $[x<y]$ denotes the function $\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ that takes value $1$ if $x<y$ and value $0$ otherwise.

Working out the first integral we find:$$\cdots=4\int_0^1\int_0^1[x<y]xydxdy=4\int_0^1\int_0^yxydxdy$$

Working out the second integral we find:$$\cdots=4\int_0^1\int_0^1[x<y]xydydx=4\int_0^1\int_x^1xydydx$$